# Download file on page load not working

Tags: javascript, download

I've been trying to get a file to download when the page loads by doing this:

```
<div onload="download()"></div>
<a id="dl" style="display: none" 
    href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/base-jumping/en/base_jumping_miniclip.swf" 
    download>Download</a>

<script>
function download(){
   document.getElementById('dl').click();
}
</script>
```

What it's supposed to do is trigger a function when the page loads that "clicks" the hidden download link. However, this method isn't working and I don't know why.

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script>
(function download() {
    document.getElementById('dl').click();
})()
</script>
```

This will execute your function right after instantiation.

Comment: Or simple `document.getElementById('dl').click();` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
window.location.href = 'http://www.miniclip.com/games/base-jumping/en/base_jumping_miniclip.swf';
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the title of the question. Then, test your answer. You'll see that it does not do what user3777369 wants.

Comment: Well I suppose they could remove the swf mime type from the server. But  the flash plugin would still render it. Either way, there is no way to override default browser functionality. Behavior like this is what hurts the internet anyway...users should get a chance to review where they are navigating to, not be tricked, which is why I spent so little time on it.

Comment: I'm not trying to trick anybody. The user will know that they're downloading something.

Comment: Ok - in that case what I suggested will achieve your desired effect:
    <script>if(confirm('Would you like to DL this file?')){window.location.href = 'http://www.miniclip.com/games/base-jumping/en/base_jumping_miniclip.swf';}</script>

Comment: That would just show the SWF file in the browser, not download it.

Comment: If you're using a browser, and you have flash plugin installed, it will always play it, not download it. Unless you manipulate the content-type of the response header at the server end of things, all solutions provided (including a self executing js function) are going to NAVIGATE to the swf file, not download it.

Comment: Not if the <a> tag has the "download" attribute. That's how the chosen solution worked.