# After reponse.End() in file download function ReturnToAction() doesn't seem to impact

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can not find a way to move pass this point, hope some one can suggest a way around.
Problem is I have a asp web application (MVC). One of the controller have an action where user downloads a file. the code in the action is as below

```
public ActionResult DownloadUserData()
    {                     
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();

        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(myfileName);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();//My guess is because response has been ended here therefore redirection below has no impact

        return RedirectToAction("ThankYouPage", "Purchases"); //This doesn't seem to work as I have an javascript in page if loaded it would show an alert          
    }
```

I have tried many variations for redirect but nothing seem to work.
Please guide

Comment: Your guess is correct. Why are you trying to return [two responses in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065697/redirect-show-view-after-generated-file-is-dowloaded)?

Comment: Just use `return File` with `FileResult` to let user downloading the file, because the later redirect response overlaps previous one.

Comment: Possible design flaw? What I am trying to do is when usef clicks a link..I bring them here.once dowload is complete I have ro update the same link in the same page..thats why I was trying this approach

Comment: Attack it the other way around. Rather than trying to download a file and redirect in the same http request (which isn't possible), just redirect to `ThankYouPage`. Inside the `ThankyouPage` do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016910/download-file-on-page-load-not-working .

Comment: HTTP is request/response. You can *either* have your response be a file *or* you can make your response indicate that they should request a different page. You can't have one response that does both of these things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the Response.End() line. It'll occur automatically when redirect is completed.

Besides, your Action should have just one action, either download a file or redirect to another page.

Is not possible to know when the download is completed on client-side by server-side, for to do anything then, because, it occurs in different requests.

If you want to update some information in page, you just can use JavaScript functions, try Ajax, it'll allow you to do something on the client-side when the request is done.

I hope it been useful for you, think about it and good code!

Answer (score 0):

How might someone typically do a file download/thankyou page? We can look at how Microsoft themselves do downloads for inspiration.

There's usually a page with a button labelled "Download". Clicking on that link just takes you to the "Thank You" page. On that second page, there are two things:

1. An explicit link to the actual download file (along with a message saying to use it if the download didn't start automatically)
2. an `<iframe>` with it's `src` set to the same location as the explicit link above.

Now, of course, you're displaying the "Thank you" message before the file is fully downloaded, but it works well enough in practice. People *expect* to see the "after" page if they've kicked off a download, even if it's going to take hours to run in practice.

You should be able to build something very similar yourself, based on this.